# C++/CLI console application hangs after Windows 10 update

Tags: c++-cli, command-line-interface, freeze

I have C++/CLI console application that uses direct sound. I am unsure if directsound is a problem or not, but after Windows 10 update application hangs before even launching. To reproduce this problem please create C++/CLI console application, link it against dsound.lib and copy paste this code into main file. You will notice that it unhangs as soon as DirectSoundEnumerate is commented.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dsound.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
static BOOL CALLBACK DSEnumOutputProc(LPGUID lpGUID,
    LPCWSTR lpszDesc,
    LPCWSTR lpszDrvName,
    LPVOID lpContext)
{
    return(TRUE);
}
void EnumerateDirectSoundDevices()
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(DirectSoundEnumerate(&DSEnumOutputProc, LPVOID(NULL))))
    {
        printf("output devices enumerated.\n");
    }
}
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We've been having this question all week long.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Yep. It seems that for me that problem was caused by free avg.. is not there some normal solution to this problem (other than uninstall) ? :)

Comment: Use an anti-malware product that's fit for a programmer's machine, not one that was designed for your Mom's machine :)  Or stop creating new executable files.

Comment: That executable is part of our product...

Comment: That's not the point.  These crappy anti-malware products get their underwear in a bundle when they see an executable program suddenly appear from no-where.  When you build it.  They'll leave you alone when you stop building.

Comment: If I try to run built product it also hangs (.exe)

Comment: Contact your virus vendor for support.